# Angular queryParams mixed binding with curly braces

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'd like to bind my component's field to `[queryParams]` attribute. Tried something like this:

```
<a routerLink="/{{getMyLink()}}" [queryParams]="{ navSource: {{navSource}} }" />
```

Where navSource is my `property` of type number. The problem is that outer braces are supposed to represent an object (according to `[queryParams]`) and the inner ones should interpolate the value. Any ideas how to escape / interpolate that value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----) with [property bindings](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-). You must use one or the other.

```
<a [queryParams]="{ navSource: navSource }" />
```

Comment: Ah, so easy, I thought I have to provide entire object on the right side when I use this syntax. Thanks !